# Scrolling through results of vim's silversearcher plug in

Tags: vim

```
When I use :Ag "pattern"
```

Let's say it finds 5 results and to scroll through them I use "cn" but it opens each one I scroll through in the buffer. Is there a way to open just the one I scroll to and click 'e' ?

Also is there a shortcut to scroll through the results except "cn" and "cp"

Answer (score 1):

I don't use the silversearcher plugin, but it sounds like it's putting its search results in Vim's quickfix error list.  That list is traversed with the `:cn` and `:cp` commands.

If you want to avoid opening the items you don't care about, you can open the list of items with the `:copen` command. Then just use `j`, `k`, and other cursor-movement commands to move the cursor to the desired item and press `<Enter>`.

To scroll through the list without the tedium of typing `:cn` and `:cp`, you can map other keys to those commands, e.g.,

```
:nmap <silent> <C-N> :cn<CR>
:nmap <silent> <C-P> :cp<CR>
```